# How to modify or remove files inside a flatpak?

Tags: flatpak

I have installed Blender 3.0.0 and am now working on an addon. During development of this addon, I need to remove one of the built-in addons (glTF Import/Export).

In a regular install, I think I would just remove something in /usr/share/* or similar. However, I'm not sure how to do so inside a flatpak.

Specifically, the directory I need to remove is, according to Blender's self-reported path:

`/app/blender/3.0/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2`

Is this possible with the flatpak command, or how do I modify ostree filesystems?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to modify/delete a file in a flatpak?

Comment: @claudekennilol I did not; however, I did discover that there is a `$HOME/.var` directory on the host system (within my home dir) where most of the files I needed were housed. It might help you also.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a similar issue; i got a flatpak with deprecated dependencies that I wanted to fix. [This](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/126) issue kinda covers hot to extract data from a flatpak, so maybe you could rebuild it when you got all the files and the manifest?